# c# Elasticsearch Nest is not filtering with Dynamic

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I can do the search well, but the filter for adult content is not working...

Doing the post with postman I can get this working, but in the .Net project where I can't do any directly post it's not working.

The documentation is not really big of nest, but the examples are too poor.

thanks in advance. cheers.

Elastic 5.3.0 (Lucene 6.4.1) & Nest 5

```
        var x5 = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
           .AllIndices()
           .Type("movies")
           .Query(qry => qry
               .Bool(b => b
               .Must(m => m
                   .QueryString(qs => qs
                       .Fields(ff => ff.Field("movie_title")
                                        .Field("movie_original_title")
                                        .Field("synopsis")
                                        .Field("cast.real_name")
                                        .Field("genre.name")
                                        .Field("sub_content.movie_title")
                                        .Field("sub_content.movie_original_title"))
                       .Query(x)))
                       .Filter(fil => fil.Terms(fil2 => fil2.Field("is_adult").Terms(false)))
                       )));
```

Comment: Can you please show query which you have in postman?

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: @RussCam just found the problem... and there is no problem. I forgot to put the size so the default output was always 10, thats why I thought it was not filtering... just added the size param and it´s working perfect. Licene 6.4.1 (elastic 5.3.0), Nest 5. cheers

Answer (score 0):

just found the error. This code is working fine, I was missing the size param, so the output was always 10. just changed and the filter is working fine.

cheers.